# Possessive usage "ours"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I often hear that in the English language one of the ways to avoid repetition is to use possessive pronouns when possible. I'd like to know if the usage in the sentence below ("ours" as a pronoun for "our world") is correct and clear:

> Many people believe that worlds depicted in fiction should look like
>   **ours**.

Comment: Why do you think not? Please see also [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

It is both correct and clear, albeit somewhat awkward.

Consider changing it to:

> Many folks believe that worlds depicted in fiction should look like
>   our own.

Comment: +1 Yup. Being grammatical isn't enough. I was about to say the same thing. But I think the question is only about the grammar; this is ELU and not writing.se